# Tag cleanup request: [astronomy]

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

There has consistently been a large amount of off-topic questions using the [astronomy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astronomy) tag.
From the tag Usage guide for [astronomy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/astronomy):

> Astronomy is the study of celestial objects, such as planets, suns, and galaxies. Any astronomy questions on this site should be programming related.

A lot of questions tagged with it seem to relate to physics, instead of programming.

Should we cleanup the posts containing this tag, or burninate this tag altogether?

### [Link of Exhibit A:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26922035/2982225)

> [image: Are there neutrinos produced during the triple alpha process? [closed]]

### [Link of Exhibit B:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26752662/2982225)

> [image: International Date Line +12 or -12 hours? [closed]]

Comment: It doesn't seem useful to me. Are people only going to be looking for astronomy programming questions, or can you have an expert in astronomy programming? I would say the physics tag is probably enough to convey what is implied by the astronomy tag.

Comment: I'd say add a comment to post such questions on Physics.SE, but that first one was *terrible*.

Comment: Due to this, I discovered the [astrophysics] tag with three questions.  It has now gotten a free preview of the heat death of the Universe.

Comment: Plan A: VtD all the closed ones, VtC those that aren't, Downvote. GoTo Plan A. Profit.

Comment: I removed the tag from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010872/in-javascript-declarations-what-does-along-with-mean). All the others seemed to be legitimate at a glance. So I guess it's whether to burn it and retag as physics.

Comment: @Radiodef: Would it be valid to make it a tag-synonym of Physics?

Comment: Personally I think so because the physics tag only has about 1,500 questions. If there is anybody following astronomy they may simply follow physics without much noise. Only a few get asked a day. I don't answer questions for either of these tags, however, so I'm not sure my opinion should carry much weight. The tag could also be useful for searching.